# Type checking a class with generic types

Tags: swift

I have a class like `SomeController<A where A: ProtA>`

I have some subclasses like `SubController: SomeController<SubA>`

Here's a working example of how I'm trying to type check:

```
protocol SomeProtocol {

}

class SuperClass<A where A: SomeProtocol> {

}

class SubProtocol: SomeProtocol {

}

class SubClass: SuperClass<SubProtocol> {

}

func classTest<A where A: SomeProtocol>(classToTest: SuperClass<A>) {
    switch classToTest {
    case is SubClass: // Has warning 'Cast from SuperClass<A> to SubClass always fails'
        print("I'm a SubClass")

    default:
        print("Wasn't found")
    }
}

classTest(SubClass()) // Prints "I'm a SubClass"
```

Functionally, the code does exactly what I want, however, I'm left with a ton of warnings saying `Cast from SuperClass<A> to SubClass always fails`

Clearly the types are related, and clearly the code runs fine and doesn't 'always fail', so this warning seems to be wrong.  Is this a current limitation or edge case of the type system, or is there a way to make the warning go away?

Comment: When you give code examples, it helps the full context, so we may more easily test it and play with it

Comment: @AMomchilov do you mean like with a Playground? I can provide an example that compiles in a Playground and shows the warning.

Comment: @trevor-e That would be fantastic.

Comment: Yeah, either a playground or a pasted code snippet

Comment: I added some playground code that demonstrates the warning.  After doing so I realized my actual code was quite a bit different from my previous code, sorry about that.

Comment: Perhaps you are architecting this the wrong way? Is there a way to avoid this dynamic type check? You've probably already watched them but maybe the "protocol oriented programming" WWDC sessions would be useful. I believe that they mention that if you have to do a cast or type check like that you are probably depriving the compiler of type information. Regardless, I don't get why the type system is complaining about this.

Answer (score 0):

Defining SuperClass as it's own generic suppresses the warning.  I also don't think you need a where clause to specify that A conforms to SomeProtocol.

```
func classTest<A:SomeProtocol, B:SuperClass<A>>(classToTest: B, useA:A) {

    switch classToTest {
    case is SubClass: // Has warning 'Cast from SuperClass<A> to SubClass always fails'
        print("I'm a SubClass")

    default:
        print("Wasn't found")
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry I don't have more information but I thought this might help!

Comment: This "works", but feels kind of hacky since you need to use A in the parameter list so that it doesn't complain about the generic type being unused.

Comment: I agree, but I thought it might be helpful toward finding another solution somehow.  I'm not sure what your requirements are but you could also change SomeProtocol to a class (as you need to specify it as a concrete type): `func classTest<B:SuperClass<SomeProtocol>>(classToTest: B)`